# How to serve static files WebApp2 NO Google AppEngine

Tags: python, webapp2

I am trying to use WebApp2 outside of AppEngine and can't find anywhere in the documentation how to set up static routes to files.

For example, I have the following folder structure

Presentation

```
-->js
-->-->main.js
-->templates
-->-->index.html (loaded via Jinja)
```

How do I reference the main.js as using ../js/main.js gives me a 404

Answer (score 1):

Here's the documentation that deals with this: [Quick start (to use webapp2 outside of App Engine)](https://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/quickstart.nogae.html). Did this not work?

Comment: +1 for a useful link, but it does not include information about static files. Serving static files occurs separately from the webapp2 application, so it depends what server OP is running their app on.

Answer (score 0):

Serving static files [should occur outside of your WSGI application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6757898/serving-static-files-with-wsgi-and-python-3) (the webapp2 `app`), so it depends on what server you are using to run your webapp2 app (which is a WSGI app), because that server will need to be configured to serve the static files. Could you please add to your question what kind of server you are using, and/or how you are running the webapp2 app?

Comment: Appreciate your response, found similar after much digging.  Problem was my lack of understanding of exactly what WebApp2 was as normal point AppEngine Dev App Server at it.

I only need a simple HTTP server, so doing the following

static_app = StaticURLParser("Presentation/")

# Create a cascade that looks for static files first, then tries the webapp
app = Cascade([static_app, web_app])

def main():
    httpserver.serve(app, host='127.0.0.1', port='8080')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate your response, found similar after much digging.  Problem was my lack of understanding of exactly what WebApp2 was as normal point AppEngine Dev App Server at it.

I only need a simple HTTP server, so doing the following

```
static_app = StaticURLParser("Presentation/")

# Create a cascade that looks for static files first, then tries the webapp
app = Cascade([static_app, web_app])

def main():
    httpserver.serve(app, host='127.0.0.1', port='8080')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and then run python main.py